# Processing: starting screen background error

Tags: java, background, processing

I am trying to create a starting screen background for my first game in Processing and it keeps erroring with the following message:

```
>When not using the PDE, size() can only be used inside settings().
Remove the size() method from setup(), and add the following:
public void settings() {
  size(800, 800);
}
IllegalStateException: size() cannot be used here, see https://processing.org/reference/size_.html
Could not run the sketch (Target VM failed to initialize).
For more information, read revisions.txt and Help ? Troubleshooting.
```

I've tried to solve the problem by following the message and by searching around but I don't manage to solve it.

this is the part for the background:

````
```
void setup() { 

bg = loadImage("rot.png");
size(800, 800);
strokeWeight( 10 );
frameRate( 30 );
background(bg);


```
````

If needed I'll send the whole part but this is where I believe the problem exist

thanks in advance

Comment: I am not sure about your problem but try putting "background(bg);" in your draw method. the setup won't help drawing the background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `settings()` method in processing has only been added in 3.0, and a lot of people just ignore it's existence. It's a great add, though, which permits stuff which the `setup()` method didn't (such as defining the window size using variables, for example).

Just move your `size()` line in a new `settings()` method, exactly as the program says.

(Also, if you are animating the sketch, you should draw the background in the `draw()` loop.)

```
PImage bg;

void settings() {
  size(800, 800);
}

void setup() { 
  bg = loadImage("rot.png");
}

void draw() {
  background(bg);
}
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the image you want to have as the background has the same form-factor as the canvas. So if the canvas size is 800x800 px, then the image has to be the same.

Good luck!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25099314)

Comment: I was only trying to help by telling him something that could be the issue to his problem.